# Print concatenated string to screen and text file using matlab

Tags: matlab, printf

This is a very basic question, but since I'm new to Matlab, I'm struggling to find a good way to do so. I just want to print some concatenated strings to screen and to a text file. Matlab is "eating" the \n !!

```
str1 = sprintf('Line 1\n');
str2 = sprintf('Line 2\n');
finalStr = strcat(str1,str2);
% Print on screen
fprintf('%s',finalStr );
% Result: Line 1Line 2. What happened to the \n ?? !!!!

% Print on file
[curPath,name,ext] = fileparts(mfilename('fullpath'));
infoPath = fullfile(curPath,'MyFile.txt');
fid = fopen(infoPath,'w'); % Write only, overwrite if exists
fprintf(fid,finalStr);
fclose(fid);
```

I also need to save finalStr to a text file.
What I'm missing here?

Comment: try %\n before the 1

Comment: also double-check this  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/45241-sprintf-format-specifiers-won-t-print-newline

Comment: From [the documentation for `strcat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html): `For character array inputs, strcat removes trailing ASCII white-space characters: space, tab, vertical tab, newline, carriage return, and form feed.` You have a trailing newline. Use [`horzcat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/horzcat.html) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function strcat ignores white spaces. In order to perform this operation, use:

```
finalStr = [str1, str2];
fprintf('%s',finalStr );
```

result:

```
Line 1 
Line 2
```

Edit:
To write the text on a text file in a "Notepad" way:

```
% Notepad needs \r also.
newline = sprintf('\n');
newlineNotepad = sprintf('\r\n');
strB = strrep(strA, newline, newlineNotepad);
```

Comment: It prints correctly on screen now, but not on the text file.

Comment: the reason is that I used the name finalstr and not finalStr. I updated my answer accordingly, it should work now.

Comment: I'm sing the correct names. In the text file the resulting text does not consider the \n.

Comment: @Pedro77 your `fprintf` call is not correct. Also, don't use notepad to view your file.

Comment: @Padro77, as excaze mentioned, use some other program such as Interner browser, notepad++ or wordPad to view that it does work for files as well

Comment: It shows correctly using WordPad or Notepad++. Why so?? I want to use notepad also.

Comment: @excaza can you please point out what is wrong with my fprintf call?

Comment: Ok, found out why, notepad need the old \r also. But if I add \r the string gets messy on the screen... Omg

Comment: Ok I came to a solution and add some info to your answer, but is peer reviewed. If it is ok, as soon it is reviewed I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also remove the use of `strcat` completely:

```
fprintf('%s%s',str1, str2);
```